# inductive proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would you proof this inductively? I know this logically makes sense and I have different ways of doing. Would you be able to tell me how and explain the reasoning behind it? Its just a simple question, not a homework assignment. Just getting a head start.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can only use induction if you are proving the inequality for positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

Base step : Since $n>1$ hence $n=2$, clearly $4>3$ so it is true.

Induction Hypothesis : Let $2n>n+1$ be true for all $k\leq n$.

Induction step : We need to show that $2(n+1)>n+1+1$, i.e., $2n+2>n+2$. But we know that $2n>n+1$ hence $2n+2>2n+1>n+2$. Thus by the principle of mathematical induction the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

If $ n > 1$ then $ n=1+m $ for some $ m > 0$. Thus $2n =2+2m$ and $ n+1= 2+m$. 
$$2n > n + 1$$ translates to:
$$2+2m> 2+m $$$$ 2m > m $$$$ 2 > 1$$ and this holds true for all $m > 0$ thus $2n> n+1$ for all $n > 1$.

Comment: Um, if $n\gt1$ then $n+n\gt n+1$? What you did is a bit too much?

Comment: @Sabyasachi - I agree that what I've said is convoluted. But saying $n+n>n+1$ is equivalent to restating the question and that would be pointless. The question is so simple that it is virtually self-evident, so I aimed to give a more thorough proof I guess.